# Limit TTask to run one at a time

Tags: delphi

I have an application that reads files added to a directory, and creates one or more PDFs from each file.  Files may be added to the directory at any time.

After a PDF is created, I am running a `TTask` to create a thumbnail image for the PDF if it is more than one page.  The procedure that I am using to create them raises an exception if more than one thumbnail is being created at the same time.  For that reason, I want to limit the `TTask` to run one at a time at most.

I had thought about several options to accomplish it, but what seemed to be the simplest solution was to run each `TTask` in a ThreadPool limited to a maximum of one worker thread.

I am creating a global variable:

```pascal
ThumbnailTaskThreadPool : TThreadpool;
```

In the application `OnCreate` event, I am adding:

```pascal
ThumbnailTaskThreadPool := TThreadPool.Create;
ThumbnailTaskThreadPool.SetMaxWorkerThreads(1);
```

When I run each `TTask`, I am adding `ThumbnailTaskThreadPool` as a parameter.

Will this work as I intend?  I realize that I could try it and see what happens, but given the nature of my application, thumbnails are not often created at the same time, so it would be difficult to tell if my code is working as intended.

Comment: Seems pointless to create a threadpool if you want to restrict it to one executing thread at a time.  Might be simplest to create a single thread and control access to it using a critical section or similar.

Comment: Just set up a thread safe queue and add the file names of the pdf files that needs a thumnail. Then empty the queue one by one and create the thumbnails.

Comment: Single thread with a producer consumer model

Comment: I had thought about making a single thread that stayed open to handle thumbnail requests.  I had difficulty coming up with a way handle additional thumbnail requests that might happen while another thumbnail was being made etc.  I have been partially handling it by sending a stringlist of the files that needed thumbnails.  That worked for multiple pdf files that I need to thumbnail at the same time but it does not work when another file is added to the directory and more thumbnails are needed when thumbnailing is already in progress.

Comment: @TreyThrasher hence the need for a thread-safe queue. The thread can run a loop that sleeps until the queue has data to process, process what is in the queue, and then go back to sleep until new data is added to the queue again. Repeat until the program is ready to exit, then terminate the thread.

Comment: Can you point me to an example?